# Access join tables

Tags: ms-access, join

Access 2007: We need a query to link two tables without using a unique field. Both tables have a field called "section" which is always three numbers.

Like this example: 
         (Table A- section=101, 208, 411...) and (Table B- section=901, 304, 208...).

This script returns an error saying

> The multi-valued field TableB.Section is not valid in the specified JOIN clause.

```
SELECT TableA.section, TableB.section...
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.Section = TableB.Section;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this if you want all the section fields intact:

```
SELECT TableA.section AS tableAsection, 
       TableB.section AS tableBsection 
FROM   TableA 
       INNER JOIN TableB 
         ON TableA.Section.Value = TableB.Section.Value;
```

You can also split into seperate fields for every multi-part of the section like so:

```
SELECT TableA.section.Value AS tableAsection, 
       TableB.section.Value AS tableBsection 
FROM   TableA 
       INNER JOIN TableB 
         ON TableA.Section.Value = TableB.Section.Value;
```